# Provide a Converter for data-binding by defining a pair of SerializableFunction objects

Tags: data-binding, vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin10, vaadin-flow

In Vaadin 8 Framework, and Vaadin 10 Flow, the data-binding capability lets us provide a [`Converter`](https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.4/8.4.5/docs/api/com/vaadin/data/Converter.html) to mediate between the widget’s expected data type (such as `String` for a `TextField`) and the data type of the backing bean property (such as `Integer` number).

In this example, the built-in `Converter` implementation [`StringToIntegerConverter`](https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.4/8.4.5/docs/api/com/vaadin/data/converter/StringToIntegerConverter.html) is used.

```
binder
.forField( this.phaseField )
.withConverter( 
    new StringToIntegerConverter( "Must enter an integer number" ) 
)
.bind( Panel::getPhase , Panel::setPhase ) ;
```

But what about defining a `Converter` for other types? How can I easily define a short-and-sweet `Converter`? For example, a String-to-[UUID](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) converter. I want to show the [canonical 36-character hex string](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#toString()) in a `TextField`, and going the other direction, [parse that string back into a UUID](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#fromString(java.lang.String)).

```
// String to UUID
UUID uuid = UUID.fromString( myString ) ;

// UUID to String
String myString = uuid.toString() ;
```

I see that [`Binder.BindingBuilder`](https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.4/8.4.5/docs/api/com/vaadin/data/Binder.BindingBuilder.html) offers the pair of methods `withConverter` that both take a pair of `SerializableFunction` objects.

- `Binder.BindingBuilder::`[`withConverter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#toString())`(SerializableFunction<TARGET,NEWTARGET> toModel, SerializableFunction<NEWTARGET,TARGET> toPresentation)`
- `Binder.BindingBuilder::`[`withConverter`](https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.4/8.4.5/docs/api/com/vaadin/data/Binder.BindingBuilder.html#withConverter-com.vaadin.server.SerializableFunction-com.vaadin.server.SerializableFunction-java.lang.String-)`(SerializableFunction<TARGET,NEWTARGET> toModel, SerializableFunction<NEWTARGET,TARGET> toPresentation, String errorMessage)`

➥ So how do I define the pair of [`SerializableFunction`](https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.4/8.4.5/docs/api/com/vaadin/server/SerializableFunction.html) objects/classes?

I noticed that this interface lists a known subinterface [`ValueProvider`](https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.4/8.4.5/docs/api/com/vaadin/data/Binder.BindingBuilder.html)`<SOURCE,TARGET>`. That looks familiar, and I have a hunch it is the key to easily defining a short simple converter. But I do not quite comprehend the syntax with lambdas and all that is going on here.

I am *not* asking how to write a class implementing [`Converter`](https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.4/8.4.5/docs/api/com/vaadin/data/Converter.html). I am asking how to write the pair of [`SerializableFunction`](https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.4/8.4.5/docs/api/com/vaadin/server/SerializableFunction.html) arguments to pass to the [`Binder.BindingBuilder::withConverter`](https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.4/8.4.5/docs/api/com/vaadin/data/Binder.BindingBuilder.html#withConverter-com.vaadin.server.SerializableFunction-com.vaadin.server.SerializableFunction-) methods listed above as bullet items.

Quoting [that JavaDoc](https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.4/8.4.5/docs/api/com/vaadin/data/Binder.BindingBuilder.html#withConverter-com.vaadin.server.SerializableFunction-com.vaadin.server.SerializableFunction-):

> `Interface Binder.BindingBuilder<BEAN,TARGET>`
>
> …
>
> `withConverter`
>
> `default <NEWTARGET> Binder.BindingBuilder<BEAN,NEWTARGET> withConverter(SerializableFunction<TARGET,NEWTARGET> toModel, SerializableFunction<NEWTARGET,TARGET> toPresentation)`
>
> Maps the binding to another data type using the mapping functions and a possible exception as the error message.
>
> The mapping functions are used to convert between a presentation type, which must match the current target data type of the binding, and a model type, which can be any data type and becomes the new target type of the binding. When invoking `bind(ValueProvider, Setter)`, the target type of the binding must match the getter/setter types.
>
> For instance, a TextField can be bound to an integer-typed property using appropriate functions such as: `withConverter(Integer::valueOf, String::valueOf);`
>
> Type Parameters:
>
> `NEWTARGET` - the type to convert to
>
> Parameters:
>
> `toModel` - the function which can convert from the old target type to the new target type
>
> `toPresentation` - the function which can convert from the new target type to the old target type
>
> Returns:
>
> a new binding with the appropriate type
>
> Throws:
>
> `IllegalStateException` - if bind has already been called

Comment: Are you asking how to make your own custom Converter?

Comment: @Jay Nope. I am *not* asking how to write a class implementing [`Converter`](https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.4/8.4.5/docs/api/com/vaadin/data/Converter.html). I am asking how to write the pair of `SerializableFunction` arguments to pass to the [`Binder.BindingBuilder::withConverter`](https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.4/8.4.5/docs/api/com/vaadin/data/Binder.BindingBuilder.html#withConverter-com.vaadin.server.SerializableFunction-com.vaadin.server.SerializableFunction-) methods listed as bullet items in my Question. Examine the JavaDoc I linked in previous sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by passing two lambda expressions to `withConverter`, so something like this:

```
binder.forField(textField)
.withConverter(text -> UUID.fromString(text), uuid -> uuid.toString())
.bind(/* ... */);
```

If you need a more complicated conversion, then the right-hand side of the lambda can be surrounded with brackets, e.g.

```
binder.forField(textField).withConverter( text -> {
    if ( text == null ) {
       return something;
    } else {
       return somethingElse;
    } 
}, uuid -> { return uuid.toString(); } )
.bind(/* ... */);
```

Comment: How does a regular Lambda qualify as a [`SerializableFunction`](https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.4/8.4.5/docs/api/com/vaadin/server/SerializableFunction.html) required by the `.withConverter` method?

Comment: It's because of Java 8 magic - and the `@FunctionalInterface` annotation on the SerializableFunction interface. Check the javadocs for some more information: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html

Comment: This does indeed work; verified in my project. But I am still confused. What is the purpose of the Vaadin team defining the `SerializableFunction` interface if we can just slip in a regular Lambda?

Comment: I realized the question asked in my previous comment is an interesting topic of its own. So I posted a separate Question, [*What purpose is served by the `SerializableFunction` interface defined in Vaadin 8 if we can simply pass a regular Lambda expression in its place?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51344045/642706)

Answer (score 1):

If you need your converter multiple times, I recommend creating a separate class implementing interface `com.vaadin.data.Converter`. However, using lambdas is possible, too, as you already know (see answer of @ollitietavainen). But this is not Vaadin specific, it's a Java 8+ feature you can read about [e.g. here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html). Basically, you can use lambdas whereever an object implementing an interface with only one method is required.